# Gauge invariant Green's function for a point particle

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, greens-functions, gauge

This question is a follow up to the question ([Gauge invariant Green's function for electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640440)).
It is not possible to generally solve the eqution
\begin{equation}
\square A^{\mu}-\partial^{\mu}\left(\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}\right)=\frac{4 \pi}{c} j^{\mu}
\end{equation}
However, if we specify the current to the current of a point particle, is there a general solution to
\begin{equation}
\square A^{\mu}-\partial^{\mu} (\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu})=\frac{4 \pi}{c}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d s v^{\mu}(s) \delta^{4}[x-z(s)]~?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640445) argument is still valid, for this expression of $j^\mu$ as for any other current distribution.

The reason is that the LHS is invariant under $A^\mu \rightarrow A^\mu  +\partial^\mu f$ for *any* function $f$, so there is no hope of find a general solution without fixing the gauge.

Comment: I dont think that hyperlink is what you intended to link to.

Comment: Indeed ^^. It should be okay now

Comment: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01017950.pdf. Originally I also thought this. But e.g. in the paper above, it is claimed that there is such a method

Comment: In the book 'Introduction to the Classical Theory of Particles and Fields by Boris Kosyakov' in 4.7 he further elaborates on the method but I am not sure if it is fully valid. I don't know if I am allowed to send screenshots. But the second half of the argument is on google book https://books.google.de/books?id=ttuO8-_D_oUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false on page 184.

Comment: Equation (4) in Kosyakov's paper fixes the gauge (although he doesn't state this explicitly). For EM, you can choose Lorentz gauge $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$ and solve using the Green function for the D'Alembertian.

Comment: Inn the book he explicitly states 'We therefore obtain not a unique solution, but rather the whole class of equivalent potentials $A^{\mu}$ related by the gauge transformations'. I understand, that the operator $\square A^{\mu}-\partial^{\mu}\left(\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}\right)$ is not invertible in general. But it could be still invertible on the subspace to which the current of the point particle belongs. I do not understand how your argument proofs, that this is also the case.

Comment: This is an affine equation : the space of solutions for any specific $j^\mu$ has the same dimension as the space of solution with $j^\mu = 0$, which is infinite because of the gauge invariance.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I want to proof that there is no solution. But gauge freedom doesn't seems a problem to me. If we assume a solution $A^{\mu}$ exists, $A^{\mu}+\partial^{\mu}f$ is also a solution leading to the same current. So we just have a class of solutions, I don't get what's the problem.

Comment: Finding a specific solution is *the same thing* as fixing the gauge. For any current density $j^\mu$ the equation $\square A^\mu-\partial^\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu =  4\pi j^\mu/c$ has infinitely many solutions, related by gauge transformations.

Comment: But we can't write those infinite solutions in a closed form which depends on $f$ and then specify a solution by fixing the $f$?. This question arises because I want to replace the $A_{\mu}$ in the action by something which only depends on the current and $f$, to get the action-at-a-distance action but without loosing gauge freedom